# HTML/CSS: Elevator Pitch Carousel?

Tags: html, css, salesforce, carousel

I'm currently working on a project and I'm interested in having a sort of "elevator pitch carousel", a feature as seen on websites like www.salesforce.com. I took a look at their source code, but I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS editing I'm pretty confused as to how to go about this.

I don't want something that is exactly as salesforces, but just generally a way how to make text in a text box change after a person presses particular heading option on the top of the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can accomplish this using javascript tabs.  Bootstrap has some pretty simple ones to implement and there are other jquery plugins that would do the basic thing.  You will need to edit the css to get the appearance you want here is a link to bootstrap 3 and their tabs feature.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

some other tabs plugins

http://www.unheap.com/?s=tabs

hope that helps

-John